# django model filter field of a field

Tags: python, django

I have this models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    draft=models.BooleanField()
    public= models.IntegerField()

class PopularArticle(models.Model):
    article=models.ForeignKey(Article)
    priority= models.IntegerField()
```

Now I want to filter like this:

```
PopularArticle.objects.filter(article.public=True,article.draft=False)
```

In word, I want to ensure that popular articles that are not in draft and already published.

How can I do that?

Comment: SyntaxError at /
keyword can't be an expression (views.py, line 9)

Comment: can you show me views.py ?

Comment: try PopularArticle.objects.filter(article__public=True), just this one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct query would be

```
PopularArticle.objects.filter(article__public=True, article__draft=False)
```

You should [look in the django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) for this. It's very well documented.